# How to interpret the p-value associated with the intercept?

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, model, intercept, gamlss

I ran a gamlss to predict my response variable Y with 2 categorical factors PROTECTION and JOUR

```
Mu Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        -1.4868     0.4652  -3.196  0.00241 ** 
PROTECTIONF         2.9102     0.8705   3.343  0.00158 ** 
PROTECTIONG         0.9573     0.8249   1.161  0.25130    
PROTECTIONR        -0.2964     0.6463  -0.459  0.64850    
JOUR2               0.5644     0.7301   0.773  0.44312    
JOUR3               2.1694     0.6026   3.600  0.00073 ***
PROTECTIONF:JOUR2  -2.4595     1.1220  -2.192  0.03306 *  
PROTECTIONG:JOUR2   0.1434     1.2090   0.119  0.90607    
PROTECTIONR:JOUR2  -0.7395     1.1297  -0.655  0.51576    
PROTECTIONF:JOUR3  -3.5884     1.1042  -3.250  0.00207 ** 
PROTECTIONG:JOUR3  -2.9856     1.0276  -2.906  0.00545 ** 
PROTECTIONR:JOUR3  -1.8282     0.9084  -2.013  0.04956 *
```

My intercept is PROTECTION T - JOUR 1

I want to establish which interactions of levels of factors are significantly different from the intercept. For this I consider the p-value, so the estimate for JOUR 3 - PROTECTION T is highly significantly different from the intercept.

**But how to interpret the p-value associated with the intercept itself ?**

Comment: The intercept tests whether the log odds for PROTECTIONF at JOUR1 is different from 0.

Comment: When you run the test, what null and alternative hypotheses are involved? If you cannot answer this for the intercept, consider what the answer is for testing a slope coefficient.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to establish which interactions of levels of factors are significantly different from the intercept.

You will get into trouble if you only depend on the coefficients and *p* values displayed here.

First, these *p* values are only against a null hypothesis of a value of 0 for each of these coefficients individually. The *p* value for the intercept just says that it's unlikely that the true value of the intercept is 0. That's seldom a comparison of interest.

There's a further problem when you evaluate other "interactions of levels of factors." Consider, for example, the situation with `PROTECTIONG` and `JOUR3`. The *interaction coefficient* (-2.99) might be significantly different from 0, but the net difference from the intercept of the estimated *outcome* under that combination is the sum of that value plus the individual coefficients for `PROTECTIONG` (0.96) and `JOUR3` (2.17): $0.96+2.17-2.99= 0.14$, which probably won't be different from 0 once the covariances among those estimates is taken into account.

With interactions it's critical to go beyond the simple display of individual coefficients and their *p* values. You need to use post-modeling tools like those provided by the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to test the types of hypotheses that you have in mind.